# indexpath.row showing index 0 every time

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, nsindexpath

So the problem is , in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method everytime indexpath.row is "0" only. And to confirm I have printed the counter with "count". But  everytime it is showing 0 and my whole table is allocated with same values. Don't know what's wrong. Please someone help .

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return [arr_Max count];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 1;
}

-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 10;
}

-(UITableViewCell *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *) indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"SimpleTableViewCell";
    count=(int)indexPath.row;

    NSLog(@"%d",count);
    SimpleTableViewCell *cell = (SimpleTableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SimpleTableViewCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    cell.label.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[arr_Max objectAtIndex:count] ];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How have you implemented numberOfRowsInSection?

Comment: Please provide more code to understand your problem.

Comment: Check my edited version

Comment: @Rahul How you have defined count variable? Have you initialise it anywhere in you code?

Comment: @Rahul You have returned count fix 1 for row count then you can get only one index with 0.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is error, the correct code is as follows:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:    (NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr_Max count];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your tableView delegate method `numberOfRowsInSection` is returning a bad number of rows.

Ensure that this required delegate method,

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

is returning a valid number - usually the number of elements in your datasource.

Comment: I guess it is because in "numberOfRowsInSection" returns only 1. I have implemented this way because I wanted to get space between cells. Please propose me the proper solution for such situation. Check my edited version

Answer (score 0):

You have update your code with following and other part will remain unchanged:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [arr_Max count];
}
```

Comment: I have implemented this way because I wanted to get space between cells. Please propose me the proper solution for such situation.

Comment: @Rahul If you want space between cells then you can put few more space at bottom of SimpleTableViewCell view.

Answer (score -1):

It seems you have number or rows = 1 (from numberOfRowsInSection).
So eachtime, when your tableview delegate fires method, it returns 1 rows only.
could you please explain more about ur problem.

For my understanding, you should go on like this code.

```
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection: 
(NSInteger)section
{
return [arr_Max count];
}
```

Then probably you will get the count value based upon your array contents.
please comment if it is ok or any query regarding this.